# Automatically notify Admin when a Workflow fails

Tags: workflow, alert

I need a function whereby an alert notification is sent automatically to Admin & List owner when a workflow is failed or not started or stops in between. Any help ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do is create a view, filtered by the status of the workflow column (not equal In progress, not equal Completed). Then you can subscribe for alerts to this specific view.

HTH

Comment: Clever!! Simple.

Comment: http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: link not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can create [SPWorkflowEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.aspx). In this receiver you have access to the [SPWorkflowEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventproperties_members.aspx). In this properties you have information about exception, thus you can send detailed information to administrators.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could automatically try to restart failed workflows using a timer job:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tejasr/archive/2010/05/26/automatically-restart-the-failed-workflow-instances.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I get a type mismatch error when attempting the proposed filtered view answer. I found an alternate solution: http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2013/02/get-notified-whenever-a-sharepoint-workflow-fails/ and it works for all the workflows for a site instead of a specific list.